# what does this mean ? Declaration is only valid at file scope

Tags: swift, button, import, scope, declaration

Hi I'm new to coding and I was wondering why this is not working. First thing first I'm trying to create a button that you click and will open a applescript that will run.

But I keep on getting this error.

**Declaration is only valid at file scope**

---

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func RunNowButton(sender: NSButton) {
        import Foundation
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
        task.arguments = ["~/Desktop/testscript.scpt"]

        task.launch()
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about Swift, but I think `import Foundation` needs to be moved outside the class. You could put it up the top, along with `import Cocoa`.

Answer (score 2):

The *import* command can only be used at "file scope" like the error is indicating. File scope means that the code is not nested inside any other code. In Swift, that basically means that the code cannot be nested inside any curly brackets (*{}*).

Let's look at a quick example:

```
// Function declared at file scope:
func someFunction() {
    // Any code here is inside the scope of "someFunction"
    // import would not be allowed
}

// Class at file scope:
class MyClass {
    // Any code here is inside the scope of "MyClass"
    // import would not be allowed
}

// import at file scope (is valid)
import Foundation
```

In this specific case, you can actually just delete the `import Foundation` line because Foundation is automatically imported when you import Cocoa which you are already doing on the very first line.

Comment: Alright i deleted import Foundation but then i get this type of error.                       osascript: ~/Desktop/testscript.scpt: No such file or directory

Comment: @Mr.X that means your Swift code is running properly but testscript.scpt does not exist in your desktop folder

Comment: The script does exist and is on my desktop but i still get this error.

Comment: @Mr.X I don't know what to tell you. osascript is clearly telling you it can't find the file. Perhaps try using the full path instead of using "~" (maybe your app is running under a different user). Otherwise make sure the command works in Terminal. Your swift code is working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can't import anything inside method, so move line

```
import Foundation
```

on top of the file.